# jest.spyOn on a class method, which is called by its reference is not working

Tags: jestjs

Consider we have class with some methods. We want to spyOn whether method A is called or not. The class looks like below.

```
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this.conf = [{ id:'1', func: this.methodA.bind(this)}, { id:'2', func: this.methodB.bind(this)}]
    }
    methodA() {
        console.log('methodA is called from methodC');
    }
    methodB() {
        console.log('methodB is called from methodC');
    }
    methodC() {
        this.conf.forEach((eachConf) => {
            eachConf.func();
        });
    }
}
module.exports = new Parent();
```

In the jest test file, calling methodC and want to ensure methodA and methodB also get called.
testSpy.js
const Parent = require('./parent');

```
it('check methodA and methodB called', async () => {
    const methodA = jest.spyOn(Parent, 'methodA');
    const methodB = jest.spyOn(Parent, 'methodB');
    Parent.methodC();
    expect(methodA).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(methodB).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

It says, Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

How to handle these type of function calls with jest?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you return `new Parent();` from the module. That means the `constructor` is already called when you mock the `methodA` and `methodB`. In the `constructor` you call `this.methodA.bind(this)`, this means in the list you store a reference to the original function bound to `this`. Later in the test you replace `methodA` and `methodB` with a mock, but there it is already to late as `this.conf` holds the reference to the original method, so mocking as no effect on the methodes in the list.

Long story short, it would be better to return only the class itself and not an instance of it

Comment: Thanks, got where its missing the mock effect